# Determine SQL schema to DbSet object in EF6

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, orm

I have code

```
const string schamaName = "schema";

public class Data: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Offer> Offers {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Place> Places{get;set;}
}

public class Offer
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<Place> Places {get;set;}
}

public class Place
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

This code will generate me three tables one for Offer, one for Place and one for mapping between two previous tables.
Now I get wanted structure, but in dbo schema.
 I want to put table Offer and mapping inside "offer" schema, third table in "dict" schema
How can I do this?

I use EF6.

I prefer to write some code inside OnCreatingModel method than use attibutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should be including Offers as a virtual Collection<>, not a DbSet<>:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual Collection<Offer> Offers {get; set;}
}
```

Also, if your schema is really "schema" instead of "dbo" then you'll need to decorate your class as follows:

```
[Table("Data", Schema="schema"]
public class Data
{
...
```

Or if you prefer OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().ToTable("Data", "schema");
```

Comment: I've edited the answer to include OnModelCreating() as well. If your table is in the dbo schema then you don't need to manually overwrite the schema in your code.

Comment: I put in question not this code which I wanted. Could you look one more time on my question? Thanks for your time and attention

Comment: 1) You should declare "public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }" instead. 2) As previous mentioned - decorate each entity with "[Table("**table name**", "**schema name**")]" to explicitly specify the name & schema.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the term "schema" correctly? In a database, a "schema" is a logical partition. In SQL Server by default it is "dbo".